# Hash tables Time Complexity Confusion

Tags: time-complexity, hashtable

I just started learning about Hash Dictionaries. Currently we are implementing a hash dictionary with separate buckets that are made of chains (linked lists). The book posed this problem and I am having a lot of trouble figuring it out. Imagine we have an initial table size of 10 ie 10 buckets. If we want to know the time complexity for n insertions and a single lookup, how do we figure this out? (Assuming a pointer access is one unit of time).

It poses three scenarios:

1. A hash dictionary that does not resize, what is the time complexity for n insertions and 1 lookup?
2. A hash dictionary that resizes by 1 when the load factor exceeds .8, what is the time complexity for n insertions and 1 lookup?
3. A hash dictionary that resizes by doubling the table size when the load factor exceeds .8, what is the time complexity for n insertions and 1 lookup?

MY initial thoughts had me really confused. I couldn't quite figure out how to know the length of some given chain for an insertion. Assuming k length (I thought), there is the pointer access of the for loop going through the whole chain so k units of time. Then, in each iteration to insert it checks if the current node's data is equivalent to the key trying to be inserted (if it exists, overwrite it) so either 2k units of time if not found, 2k+1 if found. Then, it does 5 pointer accesses to prepend some element. So, 2k+5 or 2k+1 to insert 1 time. Thus, O(kn) for the first scenario for n insertions. To lookup, it seems to be 2k+1 or 2k. So for 1 lookup, o(k). I don't have a clue how to approach the other two scenarios. Some help would be great. Once again to clarify: k isn't mentioned in the problem. The only facts given are an initial size of 10 and the information given in the scenarios, so k can't be used as the results for the time complexity of n insertions or 1 lookup.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a hash dictionary then your insert, delete and search operation will take `O(n)` of Time-Complexity for 1 key in the worst case scenario. For n insertions it would be `O(n^2)`. It doesn't matter what the size of your table is.

```
|--------|
|element1| -> element2 -> element3 -> element4 -> element5
|--------|
|  null  |
|--------|
|  null  |
|--------|
|  null  |
|--------|
|  null  |
|--------|
```

- Now for Average Case

1. Scenario one will have the load factor fixed (assuming m slots) : `n/m`. Therefore, one insert function will be `O(1+n/m)`. 1 for the hash function computation and n/m for the lookup.
2. For the 2nd and 3rd scenario it should be `O(1+n/m+1)` and `O(1+n/2m)` respectively.

For your confusion, you can ask yourself a question that what will be the expected chain length for any random set of keys. The  solution will be that we can't be sure at all.
That's where the idea of load factor comes into place to define the average case scenario, we give each slot equal probability to form a chain, if our no. of keys is greater than the slot count.

Comment: Can you explain how you found the 2nd and 3rd case to be those?

Comment: Also, wouldn't the second simplify to O(n/m) in its tightest and third to O(n/2m) in its tightest since the hash function computation is insignificant (this would be in the case of 1 insertion or 1 lookup)? Wouldn't this mean that n insertions for the second be O(n^2/m) and O(n^2/2m) for the third? Obviously this would mean the third to be O(1) amortized cost.

Comment: Yes, you are totally right. I wrote that way to make you understand.

Answer (score 0):

> Imagine we have an initial table size of 10 ie 10 buckets. If we want to know the time complexity for n insertions and a single lookup, how do we figure this out?

When we talk about time complexity, we're looking at the steepness of the n-vs-time-for-operation curve as n approaches infinity.  In the case above, you're saying there are only ten buckets, so - assuming the hash function scatters the insertions across the buckets with near-uniform distribution (as it should), n insertions will result in 10 lists of roughly n/10 elements.

During each insertion, you can hash to the correct bucket in O(1) time.  Now - a crucial factor here is whether you want your hash table implementation to protect you against duplicate insertions.

- If you simply trust there will be no duplicates, or the hash table is allowed to have duplicates (e.g. C++'s `unordered_multiset`), then the insertion itself can be done without inspecting the existing bucket content, at an accessible end of the bucket's list (i.e. using a head or tail pointer), also in O(1) time.  That means the overall time per insertion is O(1), and the total time for n insertions is O(n).
- If the implementation much identify and avoid duplicates, then for each insertion it has to search along the existing linked list, the size of which is related to n by a constant #buckets factor (1/10) and varies linearly during insertion from 1 to 1/10 of the final number of elements, so on average is n/2/10 which - removing constant factors - simplifies to n.  In other words, each insertion is O(n).

Presumably the question intends to ask the time for a single lookup done after all elements are inserted: in that case you have the 10 linked lists of ~n/10 length, so the lookup will hash to one of those lists and then on average have to look half way along the list before finding the desired value: that's roughly n/20 elements searched, but as /20 is a constant factor it can be dropped, and we can say the average complexity is O(n).

> A hash dictionary that does not resize, what is the time complexity for n insertions and 1 lookup?

Well, we discussed that above with our hash table size stuck at 10.

> A hash dictionary that resizes by 1 when the load factor exceeds .8, what is the time complexity for n insertions and 1 lookup?

Say the table has 100 buckets and 80 elements, you insert an 81st element, it resizes to 101, the load factor is then about .802 - should it immediately resize again, or wait until doing another insertion?  Anyway, ignoring that -each resize operation involves visiting, rehashing (unless the elements or nodes cache the hash values), and "rewiring" the linked lists for all existing elements: that's O(s) where s is the size of the table at that point in time.  And you're doing that once or twice (depending on your answer to "immediately resize again" behaviour above) for s values from 1 to n, so s averages n/2, which simplifies to n.  The insertion itself may or may not involve another iteration of the bucket's linked list (you could optimise to search while resizing).  Regardless  the overall time complexity is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

The lookup then takes O(1), because the resizing has kept the load factor below a constant amount (i.e. the average linked list length is very, very short (even ignoring the empty buckets).

> A hash dictionary that resizes by doubling the table size when the load factor exceeds .8, what is the time complexity for n insertions and 1 lookup?

If you consider the resultant hash table there with n elements inserted, about half the elements will have been inserted without needing to be rehashed, while for about a quarter, they'll have been rehashed once, and an eight rehashed twice, a sixteenth rehashed 3 times, a 32nd rehashed 4 times: if you sum up that series - 1/4 + 2/8 + 3/16 + 4/32 + 5/64 + 6/128... - the series approaches 1 as n goes to infinity.  In other words, the average amount of repeated rehashing/linking work done per element in the final table size doesn't increase with n - it's constant.  So, the total time to insert is simply O(n).  Then because the load factor is kept below 0.8 - a constant rather than a function of n - the lookup time is O(1).

Comment: So, Im somewhat confused although your explanation is great based on the terminology used in my class. In my course, we consider two time complexities: one being amortized where the total cost of the operations is divided by the total amount of operations and the other being normal time complexity without dividing by the total amount of operations. Considering this: I came to this 1st scenario: O(n^2) for n insertions, O(n) for lookup, 2nd scenario: O(n^2) for n insertions, O(1) for lookup, 3rd scenario: O(n) for n insertions, but O(1) amortized, and O(1) lookup. Do you agree w/ this?

Comment: I think this is the same conclusion you came to, but just wanted to make sure. On the first scenario, you said O(n) for 1 insertion (aka amortized) so for n insertions O(n^2) and O(n) for 1 lookup. Second you said: O(n) for an insertion -> O(n^2) for n insertions (not sure on this one) and O(1) for 1 lookup. Third you said: O(1) for an insertion (amortized) -> O(n) for n insertions and O(1) for 1 lookup. Is this correct or am I misinterpreting something (if I did, it might be the second scenario, clarification would be great).

Comment: Hi @amitotalllyreal - yes, those complexities are all correct if you need to check for (to disallow) duplicate keys during insertion.  If you can trust the client code not to attempt to insert duplicates, you can avoid scenario 1's list traversal during insertions.